# Conditional or unconditional exact test in R

Tags: r, chi-squared

I have a 2x2 contingency table and i want to calculate if the pair inside is significantly different.
i made a matrix like the following named raw_matrix

```
          CNS random
Not_H3K4  343  28825
H3K4      11   2014
```

Create this matrix , thus:

```
raw_matrix = structure(c(343, 11, 28825, 2014), 
    .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("NotH3K", "H3K"), c("CNS", "Random")))
```

as i searched, unconditional exact test like  Barnard’s and Boschloo’s exact tests are the most powerful test for this end. i installed the 'Exact' package and tried to do the test using this command:

```
exact.test(raw_matrix)
```

it took more than half an hour on a 64GB ram and 3.5 GH CPU computer and finally it gave the following error:

```
    Error: cannot allocate vector of size 42.0 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In matrix(A[xTbls + 1, ] * B[yTbls + 1, ], ncol = length(int)) :
  Reached total allocation of 61417Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In matrix(A[xTbls + 1, ] * B[yTbls + 1, ], ncol = length(int)) :
  Reached total allocation of 61417Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In matrix(A[xTbls + 1, ] * B[yTbls + 1, ], ncol = length(int)) :
  Reached total allocation of 61417Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In matrix(A[xTbls + 1, ] * B[yTbls + 1, ], ncol = length(int)) :
  Reached total allocation of 61417Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

then i installed 'Exact2x2' package and did the test using this command:

```
exact2x2(raw_matrix)
```

which gave me the following results:

```
    Two-sided Fisher's Exact Test (usual method using minimum likelihood)

data:  raw_matrix
p-value = 0.006433
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.2028 4.2424
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  2.178631
```

but as i read in the 'Exact'package tutorial ,  the fisher exact test which is a conditional exact test is not so powerful.  finally i did the normal chi square test using the command chisq.test(raw.matrix) which gave the following results that is different from fisher test's results:

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  test_1
X-squared = 6.2045, df = 1, p-value = 0.01274
```

im a Geneticist and not an expert in statistics, i appreciate if anybody could tell me what is the best strategy here to do this test

Comment: Thanks @spacedman for edition, but i dont see the point of that, my matrix was not right or clear enough?!!

Comment: Now anyone can cut n paste that code and create *exactly* your matrix to play with. I've just saved a minute of the life of anyone who wants to try and answer your question. Or, more like, I've maybe encouraged more people to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a lot, but I ended here studying the topic so I think I can share what I discovered.

The table you showed looks unconditional (meaning you didn't know the sums of rows or column in advance), that's fine, but it asks for a unconditional test.
This is the only question we should ask before building a contingency table: *the sums for the rows or the columns are known from the experimental design?*.

Fisher's test is fully conditional, it could be opposed in this setting (and it's been for almost all the setting except for the "[lady tasting tea](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi_nIn0nMjfAhWMMewKHYyUDE4QFjAAegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLady_tasting_tea&usg=AOvVaw2lwNX66IFHfu9Kz8jwICPB)" experiment).

Pearsons' seems fine for the case (the main concerns are about small numbers in the cells, like <5, so it should be fine), still it's widely used even if it's almost never the best choice.

The exact unconditional tests would be better (curious about how much better), but it looks like the numbers are big enough to arise computational problems, so Pearson's it is.